# Cuboc libgdx demos can't build

Tags: android, libgdx

there is something wrong with my cuboc demos of libgdx.

There are errors on every "scl" command in the demo, and it says "The method scl(float) is undefined for the type Vector2" What extra library should i need to run this demo? \

P.S. I have no problems running the metagun demo though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your libgdx library and demo source are out of sync.  The `scl` method on `Vector2` changed [5  months ago](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/fef9fc35a720ddc6b13901aaaa64113d8973c1ff#gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java).  I believe it was after 0.9.8 was released, so its part of the 'nightly' builds.

So, you should either update the cuboc demos to a nightly build, or should compile the demo you have against an older Libgdx release.

Comment: Thank you, I would try this!